# Does a Poco to DataSet project exist?

Tags: c#, dataset, poco

I have a `POCO` object that goes 4 levels deep contained objects (like `Invoice` has line items that have taxes that have gl entries), and I want to turn the entire thing into a `DataSet`. So there would be 4 tables, each with constraints being applied to the parent table.

Does anyone know of something that would automated this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219808/can-i-use-linq-to-convert-a-listmyobjecttype-into-a-dataset) question sounds similar.

Answer (score 1):

How do you populate this object? If it's from the database, there are two methods to structure your query such that the dataset is populated with separate, automatically related DataTable-s. Old and probably not supported anymore is the [SHAPE command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189657).
A better and more recent approach is to use [FOR XML](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/MappingDataSetToXMLAndBackwards.aspx).

The later approach will also allow you to load a dataset from XML-serialized representation of your `POCO' (not FOR XML, but loading XML into DataSet)

Answer (score 0):

Better JSON serialize your POCO object and then deserialize it to Dataset.
Hope this will do.